# How to determine if my Yamaha guitar is an original?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar

I recently purchased this guitar is original? The model is Yamaha SG510.

How can I determine if my newly purchased guitar is original?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don’t know squat about guitars, but as far as I know, the Y from the Yamaha logo never look like that. I’d say “fake”.

Comment: The tuners seem to be misaligned too, not a good sign.

Answer (score 4):

I grabbed a dozen or so Google Images and none look even close.  All the SG510 heads have a big logo and different font as Edouard pointed out.
Unless your axe was heavily, and badly, refinished, you're stuck.